# "database configuration does not specify adapter" error with PG gem in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Upon running "rake db:migrate", I'm getting an "database configuration does not specify adapter" error.

Here's my database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: development
  username: ##########
  password: ##########
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

My Gemfile lists:

```
gem 'pg'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Figured out what it was.  I skyped the database.yml to myself, and it inserted a ton of invisible characters which prevented the YAML from being read.

Comment: I really, really wish I were.

Comment: I really, really wish you were too, as I ran into the same problem and solved it by looking at this answer.

Comment: Oh yes, this happens when you skype some1 the database.yml content. Happened twice here, but just now I realized.

Comment: This can apparently also happen if you do `be rails c RAILS_ENV=test` (note `RAILS_ENV` is after the command). I altered the command to be `RAILS_ENV=test be rails c` and it worked. (Note: `be` is my alias for `bundle exec`).

Answer (score 9):

In my case

```
RAILS_ENV=development rake db:migrate
```

did the trick.

Comment: You can always add `export RAILS_ENV=development` to your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: Or you can type `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development` which tells rake to feed that variable into its context.

Comment: This is a bad idea.  Sometimes, you want the RAILS_ENV=test.

Answer (score 4):

Have you made sure you set the environment to development?

It's `export RAILS_ENV=development` on my mac.

Comment: Where is that placed?  It may be worth noting I'm in OSX Lion.

Comment: Type that in your terminal before starting the rails server or running the migration task

Comment: No go.  Any other ideas?  I'm still getting a "database configuration does not specify adapter", even with that executed before "rake db:migrate".

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error after some recent changes to my Rails app. First the error showed up in the `unicorn` logs, so I tried running `rake db:setup`, and got the error there too.

In my case, I somehow got an extra space placed in front of the `test` database definition. So my `database.yml` looked like this:

```
...
 test:
  adapter: postgresql
...
production:
  adapter: postgresql
...
```

instead of this:

```
...
test:
  adapter: postgresql
...
production:
  adapter: postgresql
...
```

I removed the space and that fixed the issue.